# On hover add width from left instead of right

Tags: html, css, hover, width

In this example on hover the inner div add width from the right.

I want to make it enlarge from the left inside, how to make that.

```css
#outer{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

#inner{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#inner:hover{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust the `margin-left` instead of the `width`

```css
#outer{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

#inner{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#inner:hover{
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to "pin" the div in place, probably using position or margin and then change the width.

```css
#inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: calc(50vw - 25px);
  background-color: red;
  transition: width .5s;
}

#inner:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on exactly what effect the expansion is to have.

But assuming you do want the outer element to stay at 50px and the inner element just to expand but not affect surrounding elements, you could position it absolute and right: 0. The rest of the code can remain the same (i.e. change the width).

```css
#outer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#inner:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```